# Способы загрузки файлов с сервера на ПК(Electron)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать загрузку файлов на ПК из под Electron? У меня достаточно объёмный список файлов для загрузки, нужно реализовать функцию скачки/остановки/продолжения загрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение своего вопроса, путём использования данного модуля - [Node Downloader Helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-downloader-helper)